# Model binding null values in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am trying to post data from form to action method but looks like model binder is not binding to the entities and I am getting null values in the action method, your help is much appreciated
please find the code snippet below.

**Action method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(EditRoleViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var role = await _Roleame.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);
            if (role == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("notfound");
            }
            role.Name = model.RoleName;
            var result = await _Roleame.UpdateAsync(role);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("getAllRoles", "Administrator");
            }
        }
        else {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error");
        }

        return View();

    }
```

**Model**

```
public class EditRoleViewModel
{
    public EditRoleViewModel()
    {
        names = new List<string>();
    }
    public string Id;
    [Required]
    public string RoleName;
    public List<string> names;
}
```

**View**

```
    @model FirstCoreApplication.Model.EditRoleViewModel
<script src="~/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="~/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Role";
}

<h1>Edit Role</h1>

<form method="post" class="mt-3" asp-controller="Administrator" asp-action="Update">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Id" disabled class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="RoleName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="RoleName" class="form-control">
            <span asp-validation-for="RoleName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            <a asp-action="ListRoles" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Users in this role</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @if (Model.names.Any())
            {
                foreach (var user in Model.names)
                {
                    <h5 class="card-title">@user</h5>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <h5 class="card-title">None at the moment</h5>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto">Add Users</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto">Remove Users</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.net Core 3.1 Web api request with array of objects not binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052101/asp-net-core-3-1-web-api-request-with-array-of-objects-not-binding)

Answer (score 0):

I've spent couple of hours looking for an error in my code and the reason for the binder not working in my case was using a model with public fields rather than public properties:

```
public class EditRoleViewModel
{
    public EditRoleViewModel()
    {
        names = new List<string>();
    }


    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public List<string> names { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form data you post does not match the property of your model.You do not post the parameter names .

public List names { get; set; }